# iOS BluetoothManager Framework

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi

I understand the **BluetoothManager Framework** is part of the private API, but I'm curious if anyone has any experience working with it.

I'm able to turn Bluetooth on and off, but I'd like to get a list of devices.

Calling the `pairedDevices` method seems to write all the info I need to the log, but doesn't return an array of devices.

Comment: How did you call the pairedDevices method so that you got all the data in the log?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of devices, by registering a notification for discovered devices, and then triggering the discovery itself. The incoming notification object is actually a BluetoothDevice object, that you can use to extract name and address of the remote device. There is no RSSI data built into this structure. I wrote a complete sample for OS 5.1, drop me a message if you need it.